# I am getting error while only using "Data" class library reference in my ASPNet core 1.0 Project Visual studio 2017

Tags: asp.net-core-1.0

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

> Error CS1705  Assembly 'Data' with identity 'Data, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Runtime,
>   Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
>   which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Runtime'
>   with identity 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'  "Project"   C:\Users\Sit\source\repos\WebApplication8\WebApplication8\Controllers\Login\LoginController.cs  29  Active

Answer (score 0):

First, this is an absolute *awful* question. For future reference, please refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

That said, I can parse enough from what little you gave to tell you that the issue is that your `Data` project is referencing a different version of `System.Runtime` than the application you're referencing it in, specifically a higher version. You cannot do that. Any shared references must be the same. In other words, you either need to downgrade `System.Runtime` in your `Data` project or upgrade it in your other project.

Comment: get lost Chris.